# Where to hold last sync time

Tags: android, synchronization, timestamp

I have an android application which is updated every 30 seconds to retrieve latest messages from a server. Currently I use a time-stamp which holds the seconds from beginning of 2016 inside server database for both **user last sync** and also for **messages** to detect the messages which need to be delivered.

I am afraid which approach is more safe to hold the sync time to prevent losing data for reasons like disconnection or any kind of error within the sync process:

1. current approach (hold last sync time on the server)?
2. hold last sync time in client database (is subject to hack?)?
3. defining a custom process to make sure the data is delivered (like online payments confirmation)?

Comment: Generally the client should know when the last sync was and fetch what is needed...But how is `subject to hack` an issue? It is a timestamp. Worst case it gets reset or invalidated and the client does a full sync

Comment: Thanks. Why the client should know the last sync time?

Comment: Since the user can reset (clear app data, uninstall, ...) any time

Comment: The question is, why do you consider "hacking" an issue?

Comment: Just as a possible issue! For example bombing the server to push all messages every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking most approaches to servers and APIs are stateless.

By storing sync dates on the server you prevent the user from *reinstalling* or *resetting* their app. Since they would only fetch the latest data. This might be the wanted approach (e.g. Snapchat will keep no history (at least on the client)) but if you want to list past data this willl just complicate things.

If you chose to store it on the client you can be more confident in the user getting the data he needs. To prevent attacks on your servers you should use other mechanisms. If the user clears his data, he would just fetch all the required information again, since the client knows when and what to update.

Your third approach would be similar to the first one, but with more confidence on the latest state. You would know what the user read and retrieved, but you would still be storing state on your server.

All this said, it strongly depends on your actual goals and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way: Once new data fetched, the client should send a confirmation to the server... By doing this, the server would be sure of the exact moment the client was last synced... and would avoid any data loss due to *whatever* reason (connexion lost, etc.)